# Pattern Matching JSON Requests in Play Framework WebSocket with Actor

Tags: json, scala, playframework, websocket

I'm trying to use Play framework Scala version to implement a WebSocket server. Now I can send and receive messages back and forth, they are working fine.

Here's my controller action:

```
def socket: WebSocket = WebSocket.accept[InEvent, OutEvent] { request =>
  ActorFlow.actorRef { out =>
    ChatActor.props(out)
  }
}
```

And I got my InEvent, OutEvent and JSON formatter:

```
case class OutEvent(content: String)
case class InEvent(content: String)

implicit val inEventFormat = Json.format[InEvent]
implicit val outEventFormat = Json.format[OutEvent]

implicit val messageFlowTransformer =
    MessageFlowTransformer.jsonMessageFlowTransformer[InEvent, OutEvent]
```

And the underlying actor:

```
class ChatActor(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive: Receive = {
    case InEvent(msg) =>
      out ! OutEvent(s"received: $msg")
  }
}
```

Currently I only have one case class for request, and one case class for response. That's totally cool.

However if I wanted to add more type of messages, I cannot make it work with subtype or inheritance. Here's some fake code to show what I wanted to achieve but actually not working:

The messages:

```
trait Event
case class OutEvent1(content: String)
case class InEvent1(content: String)

case class OutEvent2(body: Int)
case class InEvent2(body: String, content)
```

The actor:

```
class ChatActor(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive: Receive = {
    case InEvent1(msg) =>
      out ! OutEvent1(s"received: $msg")
    case InEvent2(body, content) =>
      out ! OutEvent2(01234)
  }
}
```

I found though it is extremely easy to implement in dynamic language like JavaScript and basically I can just leave a property as a type tag so I can just assume the type and get other properties, it's quite hard to implement in statically typed language for make everything works easily (and hopefully less verbose).
So my question is how to make deserializing subtypes works in this case, so I can make those message type extensible?

Comment: Shouldn't `case InEvent2(body, content)` take one param?

Comment: Sorry. I edited the code a little bit to fit the intention before post the question but I made some mistake on those case classes.